# FlashChat with Firebase Error

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, authentication

I am trying to build a flash chat app from a 'course' using Firebase but I keep getting stuck on this issue. Help will be greatly appreciated. I will be posting my app Gradle file as well. The instructor may be using an outdated of Android Studio and may have used old dependencies in the Gradle file so after research I decided to change it but it still does not work. Please assist me so I can complete this course. Thanks

```
05-09 09:17:44.777 2668-2668/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase, PID: 2668
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase/com.online.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.online.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.online.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
    05-09 09:18:15.891 2668-2761/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase    
    E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
    05-09 09:19:15.958 2668-2761/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase  
    E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
    05-09 09:20:45.975 2668-2761/com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase 
    E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Below is my app Grade file.:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'




    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
   }

    dependencies {



implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'


    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase;



public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // TODO: Add member variables here:
    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.integer.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // TODO: Grab an instance of FirebaseAuth

    }

    // Executed when Sign in button pressed
    public void signInExistingUser(View v)   {
        // TODO: Call attemptLogin() here

    }

    // Executed when Register button pressed
    public void registerNewUser(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase.RegisterActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // TODO: Complete the attemptLogin() method
    private void attemptLogin() {


        // TODO: Use FirebaseAuth to sign in with email & password



    }

    // TODO: Show error on screen with an alert dialog
```

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
package com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Constants
public static final String CHAT_PREFS = "ChatPrefs";
public static final String DISPLAY_NAME_KEY = "username";

// TODO: Add member variables here:
// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private AutoCompleteTextView mUsernameView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private EditText mConfirmPasswordView;

// Firebase instance variables

private FirebaseAuth  mAuth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
    mConfirmPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_confirm_password);
    mUsernameView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.register_username);

    // Keyboard sign in action
    mConfirmPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.integer.register_form_finished || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptRegistration();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    // TODO: Get hold of an instance of FirebaseAuth

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}

// Executed when Sign Up button is pressed.
public void signUp(View v) {
    attemptRegistration();
}

private void attemptRegistration() {

    // Reset errors displayed in the form.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // TODO: Call create FirebaseUser() here
        createFirebaseUser();

    }
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    // You can add more checking logic here.
    return email.contains("@");
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    //TODO: Add own logic to check for a valid password (minimum 6 characters)

    String confirmPassword = mConfirmPasswordView.getText().toString();
    return confirmPassword.equals(password) && password.length() > 4;
}

// TODO: Create a Firebase user
private void createFirebaseUser(){
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d("FlashChat", "createUser onComplete: " + task.isSuccessful());

            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d("FlashChat", "user creation failed");
            }
        }
    });

}

// TODO: Save the display name to Shared Preferences


// TODO: Create an alert dialog to show in case registration failed




   }
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.online.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase.LoginActivity". did you put it in a different package?

Comment: No. I will add the LoginActivity file. please view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your package says "com.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase;" you can see the difference  from your crash log which says

> Didn't find class "com.**online**.lucianvibez.flashchatnewfirebase.LoginActivity"

notice the "online" is missing from your package?

I suspect that your Manifest file has online in it, so the app is confused when your manifest says to lookup loginActivity in a path that does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much. I remembered refactoring then renaming the entire package. Something may have happened accidentally on my part during that time. Thanks again